# C -printf casting

Tags: c, printf, rounding, short, truncation

I want to play with overflow of signed short integer variable. I declare variable *a1* as short, and then I give the greater positive value, zero is 'considered' positive, so maximum value of a signed integer (be it short, int, long or long long) must be exp2(8*sizeof(*variable*)-1)-1, mustn't it?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{

int short a1=2;

a1=exp2(8*sizeof(a1)-1)-1;

printf("The last value that DOES NOT overflow in a integer as \'signed short\' (%i bytes) is %hi.\nIf I define this variable equal to this value I get the value in the variable %hi.\n",(unsigned char) sizeof(a1), (short) exp2(8*sizeof(a1)-1)-1, a1);/*key word short from "(short) exp2(8*sizeof(a1)-1)-1"*/

a1=exp2(8*sizeof(a1)-1);/*warning-overflow: "warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]"*/

printf("The 1st value that overflows in a integer as \'signed short\' (%i bytes) is %i.\nIf I define this variable equal to this value instead I get the value in the variable %i.\n",(unsigned char) sizeof(a1), (int) exp2(8*sizeof(a1)-1), a1);/*key word int from "(int) exp2(8*sizeof(a1)-1)"*/
return;
}
```

So I get a overflow-warning, as I wanted, that's the target of this code:

> warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]

Then ./a.out and the output is

> The last value that DOES NOT overflow in a integer as 'signed short'
>   (2 bytes) is 32766.
>       If I define this variable equal to this value I get the value in the variable 32767.
>       The 1st value that overflows in a integer as 'signed short' (2 bytes) is 32768.
>       If I define this variable equal to this value instead I get the value in the variable 32767.

The 2nd printf works fine, doesnt it? But the 1st I think should show the same value to printf of variable a1 (a1=exp2(8*sizeof(a1)-1)-1;) and to the casting of (short) exp2(8*sizeof(a1)-1)-1.
I rewrite it more clear:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
int short a1=exp2(CHAR_BIT*sizeof(a1)-1)-1;
printf("It should be %hi = %hi.\n",(short) exp2(CHAR_BIT*sizeof(a1)-1)-1, a1);
return;
}
```

And the output is

> It should be 32766 = 32767.

When I think it should be: "It should be 32767 = 32767."

Help me to understand it please

**SOLVED** by @chux

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <float.h>


int main()
{
int short a1=exp2(CHAR_BIT*sizeof(a1)-1)-1;
printf("It should be %hi = %hi.\n",(short) (round(exp2(CHAR_BIT*sizeof(a1)-1))-1), a1);
return;
}
```

I must remark that brakets here are important, without them, I mean `(short) round(exp2(CHAR_BIT*sizeof(a1)-1))-1`, you get another value.

Comment: Prefer `CHAR_BIT` rather than `8` ... don't forget to `#include <limits.h>`

Comment: Overflow of a signed integer is undefined behavior. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic.

Comment: I did as you suggested, thx btw, and I get the same resaults: inline `#include<stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
int short a1=exp2(CHAR_BIT*sizeof(a1)-1)-1;
printf("It should be %hi = %hi.\n",(short) exp2(CHAR_BIT*sizeof(a1)-1)-1, a1);
return;
}`

Comment: you overflow it, and as it's an undefined behaviour, the compiler throws a warning... There is no error or problem here.

If you don't want the warning use bitwise operation instead of exp2:
`a1=1<<((8*sizeof(a1)-1));`

Comment: @yakoudbz thanks for the answer, I may not explain the problem right. The folowing command `a1=exp2(8*sizeof(a1)-1)-1;
printf("It should be %hi = %hi.\n",(short) exp2(8*sizeof(a1)-1)-1, a1);` shoud show `It should be 32767 = 32767.`, but instead it shows `It should be 32766 = 32767.`

Comment: @yakoudbz shifting into the sign bit is also undefined behavior (since shifting left is defined in terms of multiplying by the appropriate power of two).

Comment: What is `exp2()`? This does not compile.

Comment: Not understand the question. If I supply a function `exp2(int pow)` that returns `2^pow` either as `double` or as `int`, the value that does NOT overflow is `32767` and the value that DOES overflow is `32768` which when cast as `short` is `-32768`. What's the problem? I don't know where you are getting `32766` from.

Comment: Let us just forget the overflow and just study if the out put of the following program make sense please.`#include<stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
int short a1=exp2(CHAR_BIT*sizeof(a1)-1)-1;
printf("It should be %hi = %hi.\n",(short) exp2(CHAR_BIT*sizeof(a1)-1)-1, a1);
return;
}`

Comment: The output that I get is: `It should be 32766 = 32767.` And that doesnt make sense, does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`double` to `int` truncation.

The unposted non-standard function `exp2()` is certainly `double exp2(double x)` and not well implemented.

When converting small `int` to `double` as in passing the argument to `exp2(8*sizeof(a1)-1`, the conversion is exact.

When taking the result and converting to `short` as in `short a1=exp2()`, **that** is the issue.  Suppose the result of `exp2(15)` slightly in error and was 32767.99999999 instead of the hoped for 32768.0.  Then conversion to to `int` is "truncation toward 0".

Often the solution is to *round* before truncation.

```
// add  vvvvvv                           v 
(short) round(exp2(CHAR_BIT*sizeof(a1)-1)) - 1
```

---

Try debugging with the following to see the return value with enough precision.

```
#include <float.h>
int short a1;
printf("%.*f\n", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG - 1, (double) exp2(CHAR_BIT*sizeof(a1)-1));
```

Comment: Than you @chux for the good explanation and for solving it!! May you recommend any chapter of book or webpage to learn more about truncation in C?

Comment: @daniel See [draft of the C11 standard](www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf) "6.3.1.4 Real floating and integer"